# Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services: Recommendation outputs capitalized item id

Tags: api, azure, recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

I made a catalog and usage file and built/updated a model. I registered items' id using upper and lower case characters like this:

> VYVFNEjAxUHn8cqI

Of course built or updated model are suceeded.

I get capitalized item id from MS Recommendation GET API(Both I2I and U2I) like this:

> VYVFNEJAXUHN8CQI

This service is not case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the internal comparison is case sensitive for UserId.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the system is not case sensitive for userIds or itemIds.

If you have case sensitive IDs, we would recommend you encode them (i.e. base32 encode them) before using the Recommendations Service.

Thanks!
-Luis Cabrera
Cortana Intelligence Applications